# Why does our teleport work differently?

Tags: starbound

My friend and I noticed something odd while playing Starbound. For some reason, I was perfectly capable of teleporting out from underground while he could not do such a thing. We initially thought it might be that he would need to get a fully upgraded ship but, even then, he still couldn't.

We've had a few thoughts about what it might be, most likely one in our heads dealing with the fact that I created my character immediately after 1.0 came out and he did his a few weeks ago. I checked the changelogs but, I failed to find anything mentioning such a change.

We are at the same tech levels and are at the same point progress-wise (the end).

**Why can I teleport out from underground while he is unable to do so?**

**Edit**: I'm able to teleport out from any depth, with or without a wall behind me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're both on same depth level, you most likely didn't have a wall behind you (RMB with the tool to break it down).
You can't teleport to ship from within buildings, which mainly just means you can't teleport if you have a wall behind you.
Edit: An update in 2016 made it possible to beam to ship from any depth with walls behind you if your character is in **casual mode.**

Comment: Ah sorry I should have mentioned that in the question, I'm able to teleport out from any depth, even if there is a wall behind me. I even tried going to the core of a planet and, with a wall, was still able to teleport out.

Comment: Do you have a mod installed allowing you to do that? Because in vanilla game, it is not possible to teleport to ship if you have a wall behind you or past certain depth.

Comment: Nope. Only mod installed is a Dark Souls one that my friend has installed as well.

Comment: @santyclause I updated the answer with what's most likely causing this "issue".